# DHT22 interfacing with 8051

Tags: c, sensors, lcd, 8051

I have tried to connect dht22 sensor with 8051 microcontroller in 4 bit mode. But I am not able to get the proper temperature and humidity readings. Someone please help me with the code.

I am getting the temperature and humidity readings as
Hum= 2.88%
Temp=1.0C  91

Please help me to get the correct temperature and code readings. I have included the code for dht22 sensor and LCD.

My code is:

```
#include<reg51.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<intrins.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "LCD16x2_4bit.h"

sbit DHT22=P2^1;        /* Connect DHT22 output Pin to P2.1 Pin */
int I_RH,D_RH,I_Temp,D_Temp,CheckSum; 

void timer_delay20us()
{
    _nop_();_nop_();_nop_();_nop_();_nop_();                                     
    _nop_();_nop_();_nop_();_nop_();_nop_();                                        
    _nop_();_nop_();_nop_();_nop_();_nop_();                                       
    _nop_();_nop_();_nop_();_nop_();_nop_();                                        
                                           
}

void Request()          /* Microcontroller send request */
{
    DHT22 = 0;      /* set to low pin */
    delay(1);   /* wait for 1ms */
    DHT22 = 1;      /* set to high pin */
}

void Response()         /* Receive response from DHT22 */
{
    while(DHT22==1);
    while(DHT22==0);
    while(DHT22==1);
}

int Receive_data()      /* Receive data */
{
    int q,c=0;  
    for (q=0; q<8; q++)
    {
        while(DHT22==0);/* check received bit 0 or 1 */
        timer_delay20us();    //delay 20us
        if(DHT22 == 1)  /* If high pulse is greater than 28us */
        c = (c<<1)|(0x01);/* Then its logic HIGH */
        else
        c = (c<<1);  /* otherwise its logic LOW */
        while(DHT22==1);                                     
    }
    return c;
}

void main()
    unsigned char dat[20];
    LCD_Init();     // initialize LCD 
    
    while(1)
    {       
        Request();  // send start pulse
        Response(); // receive response
        
        I_RH=Receive_data();    // store first eight bit in I_RH
        D_RH=Receive_data();    // store next eight bit in D_RH
        I_Temp=Receive_data();  // store next eight bit in I_Temp
        D_Temp=Receive_data();  // store next eight bit in D_Temp
        CheckSum=Receive_data();// store next eight bit in CheckSum

        if ((I_RH + D_RH + I_Temp + D_Temp) != CheckSum)
        {
            LCD_String_xy(0,0,"Error");
        }
        
        else
        {

            sprintf(dat,"Hum = %d.%d",I_RH,D_RH);
            LCD_String_xy(0,0,dat);
            LCD_String("%");
            sprintf(dat,"Temp = %d.%d",I_Temp,D_Temp);   
            LCD_String_xy(1,0,dat);
            LCD_Char(0xDF); // to print 0 (degree) in LCD 
            LCD_String("C");
            sprintf(dat,"%d   ",CheckSum);
            LCD_String_xy(1,13,dat);
        }       
        delay(3000);
    }

} 


/*  
   LCD16x2 4 bit 8051 interface
*/


#include<reg51.h>
#include<LCD16x2_4bit.h>

sfr LCD_Port=0x90;                          /* P1 port as data port */
sbit rs=P1^0;                               /* Register select pin */
sbit rw=P1^1;                               /* Read/Write pin */
sbit en=P1^2;                               /* Enable pin */

/* Function to provide delay Approx 1ms with 11.0592 Mhz crystal*/
void delay(unsigned int count)          
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    for(j=0;j<112;j++);
}

void LCD_Command (char cmnd)    /* LCD16x2 command funtion */
{
    LCD_Port =(LCD_Port & 0x0F) | (cmnd & 0xF0); /* sending upper nibble */
    rs=0;                                           /* command reg. */
    rw=0;                                           /* Write operation */
    en=1; 
    delay(1);
    en=0;
    delay(2);

    LCD_Port = (LCD_Port & 0x0F) | (cmnd << 4);  /* sending lower nibble */
    en=1;                                           /* enable pulse */
    delay(1);
    en=0;
    delay(5);
}

void LCD_Char (char char_data)  /* LCD data write function */
{
    LCD_Port =(LCD_Port & 0x0F) | (char_data & 0xF0); /* sending upper nibble */    
    rs=1;                                               /*Data reg.*/
    rw=0;                                               /*Write operation*/
    en=1;                   
    delay(1);
    en=0;
    delay(2);

    LCD_Port = (LCD_Port & 0x0F) | (char_data << 4);  /* sending lower nibble */
    en=1;                                           /* enable pulse */
    delay(1);
    en=0;
    delay(5);
}

void LCD_String (char *str)         /* Send string to LCD function */
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;str[i]!=0;i++)              /* Send each char of string till the NULL */
    {
        LCD_Char (str[i]);                  /* Call LCD data write */
    }
}

void LCD_String_xy (char row, char pos, char *str)  /* Send string to LCD function */
{
    if (row == 0)
    LCD_Command((pos & 0x0F)|0x80); /* Command of first row and required position<16 */
    else if (row == 1)
    LCD_Command((pos & 0x0F)|0xC0); /* Command of first row and required position<16 */
    LCD_String(str);                                /* Call LCD string function */
}

void LCD_Init (void)                            /* LCD Initialize function */
{
    delay(20);                  /* LCD Power ON Initialization time >15ms */
    
    LCD_Command (0x02);             /* 4bit mode */
    LCD_Command (0x28);             /* Initialization of 16X2 LCD in 4bit mode */
    LCD_Command(0x0C);              /* Display ON Cursor OFF */
    LCD_Command (0x06);             /* Auto Increment cursor */
    LCD_Command (0x01);             /* clear display */
    delay(3);
    LCD_Command (0x80);             /* cursor at home position */
}

/*
 * LCD16x2 4 bit 8051 interface
*/

#ifndef LCD16x2_4bit
#define LCD16x2_4bit

#include<reg51.h>

void delay(unsigned int count);
void LCD_Command (char cmnd);
void LCD_Char(char char_data);
void LCD_String(char *str);
void LCD_str(unsigned char *, unsigned char);   
void LCD_String_xy (char row, char pos, char *str);
void LCD_Init (void);
void delay_ms(unsigned int);

#endif
```

Comment: It is impo...very, very difficult to debug sotware/hardware systems by means of text exchanges.  You have the environment, all software, hardware, compiler, linker, loader,debugger, logger, meter, scope etc.  We only have some source code we can look at.  You are in a far better position to fix your issues than we are.

Comment: Did you try to use an oscilloscope to see what the sensor transmits? You might like to use another port pin to show a small pulse in your `Receive_data()` function so check how you are reading the transmission. -- What else have you tried? Do you read varying values? -- See, our crystal balls are in quarantaine, too.

Answer (score 1):

Your program can work properly for DHT11; and this program will not work with DHT22. The reason is that DHT11 and DHT22 have different data formats.

If we don't consider the sign bit, the true temperature is equal to `(I_Temp\*256 + D_Temp)/10` and the true humidity is equal to `(I_Temp\*256+D_Temp)/10`. A little modification will solve your problem.